# Chronicle queue events listener

Tags: java, events, listener, chronicle, chronicle-queue

1) In [chronicle queue v4](https://github.com/OpenHFT/Chronicle-Queue) most [test patterns](https://github.com/OpenHFT/Chronicle-Queue/tree/master/src/test/java/net/openhft/chronicle/queue) show some form of `DocumentContext.isPresent()` [busy state checking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_waiting), when `ExcerptTailer` is positioned at the end of the queue and **code is waiting** for new entries to arrive from `ExcerptAppender`.

2) Is there a built-in chronicle queue mechanism for asynchronous `appender -> tailer` notifications, such that upon receipt of a notification event, given `tailer` is guaranteed to have at least one entry posted by `appender`, **ready for read**?

3) If not, what is **recommended pattern** to implement such `event listener`? Please share a working example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The recommended pattern for implementing a listener pattern is to use the methodReader/methodWriter which can also take care of timestamps when where you read was up.

I suggest you read these https://vanilla-java.github.io/tag/Microservices/ from the bottom up starting with Part 1.

For the tailer, the only way it know there is a message is by reading/polling the end of the queue. If the appender and tailer are in the same process you can use a different mechanism of your choice.

Comment: A) re: **use the methodReader/methodWriter** -  from [part-2](https://vanilla-java.github.io/2016/03/24/Microservices-in-the-Chronicle-world-Part-2.html) and [MethodReader.readOne()](https://github.com/OpenHFT/Chronicle-Wire/blob/master/src/main/java/net/openhft/chronicle/wire/MethodReader.java#L198) it seems that `readOne()` is semantically identical `isPresent()`, i.e. there no event notification or blocking going on,  correct?

Comment: B) re: **in the same process you can use a different mechanism** - in this case, what is `ExcerptAppender` /  `ExcerptTailer` synchronization contract? i.e. is `appender...doc.close()` is a guarantee that `tailer...doc.isPresent()` will see the change, when notified after `appender...doc.close()`?

Comment: @AndreiPozolotin correct. There is no blocking action.

Comment: @AndreiPozolotin as soon as close is called the record is visible.

Comment: @AndreiPozolotin you can use a Pauser on the Tailer and you can unparsed it on the appender for a low latency signal.

Comment: @AndreiPozolotin I meant `unpause`, rather than `unparsed` ;)